# How to slow down Android UI rending?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, rendering, developer-tools

How can I slow down UI rending in Android to get an idea of how UI is rending?
There is an option in Developer Tools where you can slow down animation speed.

My UI is changing with some flashing, but I am not able to get actual since too fast.
Is there any tool or some idea for a workaround to emulate "slow rendering".

Any tool specific to `compose` is also welcomed.

Comment: The rendering is tied in to the refresh rate of the device and I do not know of such an option in the emulator.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Eliminating the flashing?  That's generally too many redraw events occurring, and the solution is to reduce those.

Comment: Since the flash is so fast, I am not able to understand what is causing the flash. So I thought if I slow down rendering (like speed down animation) I might be able to understand where the flash is occurring.